# STM32CubeIDE - No STLink Detected

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, nucleo

I am working with a Nucleo Board (Nucleo F401RE) and I have a problem with "STM32CubeIDE 1.9.0".

When I try to flash the code using the IDE debuggar I get an error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsPn6.png)

At this point I tried to connect using the "cube programmer" through which I can connect correctly and flash the code.

I am also attaching my debug settings where, as you can see, I can see the serial of my STLINK correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe0c4.png)

I also tried to uninstall all of them, including drivers, and the problem did not go away, what could be the problem?

Comment: Try to attach some logs. Have you checked the adapter listed is your debug configuration is the right one?

Comment: @Damiano I tried to enable the LOG of the debugger interface but it does not generate the file, I think it blocks before the generation of the file, also because it does not write anything to me on the console.

How can I check if the configuration is correct what can I try to change? Thank you for the support!

Comment: Try starting the server externally look here https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2576-stm32cubeide-stlink-gdb-server-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: You can't run both STM32CubeProgrammer and STM32CubeIDE at the same time. Close STM32CubeProgrammer or at least disconnect it from target.

Answer (score 0):

try connecting the board to your pc. that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing happens when ST-LINK is connected to another application other than IDE (my guess is it is connected to cube programmer). So click disconnect on the other app and debug in you IDE.